# How can i make it play music?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried making a rickroll command like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith('music plz')) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) {
        return message.reply(`Wow what a scrub, join a Voice Channel first`);
    }
    voiceChannel.join()
.then(connection => {
    const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ', { filter: 'audioonly' });
    const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
})
```

It joins the VC and gives an error when not in VC but does not play music what am I doing wrong? I use `Discord.js v12.5` and I am new to
it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error

Comment: Might be the back ticks in your `message.reply` - change those to single quotes.

Comment: That isn't the problem, that's valid syntax

Comment: @Elitezen It joins the voice channel and also gives an error when not in it but does not play anything so I am asking what's the thing I have done wrong here.

Comment: @disinfor did it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide [Here](https://v12.discordjs.guide/voice/voice-broadcasts.html#playing-audio) they have a guide of how to do this. Also please update to `v13`, it's much better. Something like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();

// From a path
broadcast.play('audio.mp3');
// From a ReadableStream
broadcast.play(fs.createReadStream('audio.mp3'));
// From a URL
broadcast.play('http://myserver.com/audio.aac');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, K.K Desgins!